Firebase CLI not letting me register the app without package name, not even letting me provide one
I was registering my flutter project with the firebase project that I created on the website. I followed the steps there and along the way it asked me for the package name (application id) which it's not letting me provide it. If I continue, it throws error. 
This wasn't happening before. Any help would be appreciated.

Unless you have specific steps to reproduce this from a fresh project, and you think you might be doing something wrong, this should be filed as a bug report against flutterfire.  The volunteers of Stack Overflow are not very well suited to tell you what you're doing wrong here, if anything.
